# When are we justified in taking the determinants of two "equal" matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a proof that began with $AB = I$ where $A, B$ are square matrices and $I$ is the identity matrix. Then, the proof mentions that $\det(AB) = \det(I)$. I am trying to understand why it is valid to take the determinants of the two matrices given that $AB = I$. I read online that the determinants of two similar matrices are equal which might justify $\det(AB) = \det(I)$ but I have not read anything about similar matrices in the linear algebra course that I am taking.

So, is it valid to say that the determinants of two row equivalent matrices (here: $AB$ and $I$)  are equal as a justification for the $\det(AB) = \det(I)$ step of the proof?

Comment: The determinants of two equal matrices are equal.

Comment: I mean, you are saying "**the** determinant", not "**a** determinant", are you not?

Comment: For instance, if I say $A=\begin{pmatrix}11 &2\\ 14& 7\end{pmatrix}$, then I expect you to question the truth of the statement $\det(A)=49$. I *can* see a particular semantic interpretation where someone should question such a statement, but I'd like to hear your objection first.

Comment: You are actually using the fact that if $X = Y$ then $\det(X) = \det(Y)$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I am not sure if I follow your question. If I have, say, a matrix $A$ with the values you mentioned, wouldn't it's determinant be unique? Then, am I not justified in saying "the determinant" instead of "a determinant"? Are you referring to a certain portion of my question in particular? I'm sorry I don't follow your argument yet

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson That's kind of my point. For some reason, if instead of $A$ I consider $AB$ on the LHS (which is the same as specifying the assertion to the case where $A$ is the may be written as the product of two meatrices), and I put  $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{pmatrix}11&14\\2&7\end{pmatrix}$ on the RHS, then you start questioning it.

Comment: If two things are equal, and you do something to the LHS, and you do the same thing to the RHS, then the result will also be equal (pretty much by definition of "being equal").